# Spring Boot Deployment on Tomcat7 and Log4 issue

Tags: maven, spring-boot, tomcat7

I am trying to run my spring boot app on standalone tomcat. However it gives me this error

```
java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletContainerInitializer
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1579)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1280)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:888)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5522)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletContainerInitializer
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:197)
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>codingtest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>codingtest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.paralleluniverse</groupId>
            <artifactId>comsat-tomcat-loader</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run the application in Eclipse it works without any issue. The issue only happening when I run it on the standalone Tomcat 7.

**UPDATE**

I notice the missing class was used by

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>co.paralleluniverse</groupId>
            <artifactId>comsat-tomcat-loader</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I tried to remove the dependency and install the war file on Tomcat 7. This time I got different error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
        ... 15 more

Feb 03, 2017 7:37:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.73\webapps\ROOT.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:903)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I look at the guide http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging it seems to be easy peasy. But it is not in real life.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: By saying "running it on the Tomcat 7" you want to say you compiled a WAR file and deploy it on the server? Usually it is because you don't pack the Apache Logging jar. I don't see it in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Yes I compiled it as war file and deploy it on the server. I tried adding `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  </dependency>` but the result is the same. In fact when I searched within Eclipse I find the class 'Log4jServletContainerInitializer' is within `comsat-tomcat-loader` dependency.

Comment: Put the jars under Tomcat 7 `libs`? I have been in some situation like yours and that hack saved me.

Comment: I dont have access to the Tomcat7 folder. I need to ship this to a client and expect it to work out of the box.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer. You probably have to follow the Spring Boot instructions on how to [Configure Log4j for Logging](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix it I did the following

1. Removed `comsat-tomcat-loader` dependendcy which uses log4j (thanks to @FrVaBe).
2. Extended my Spring Boot application with `SpringBootServletInitializer` as mentioned in docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/

Answer (score 1):

Use slf4j, Spring boot comes with slf4j and all the standard loggers you do not need any extra dependency

```
$ jar tvf target/spring-boot-0.1.0.jar | egrep 'log|slf'
 41077 Tue Dec 13 18:07:58 GMT 2016 BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar
470633 Fri Dec 09 11:03:02 GMT 2016 BOOT-INF/lib/logback-core-1.1.8.jar
 16521 Tue Dec 13 18:09:00 GMT 2016 BOOT-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
305137 Fri Dec 09 11:05:04 GMT 2016 BOOT-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.8.jar
 23647 Tue Dec 13 18:09:06 GMT 2016 BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
  2310 Thu Dec 22 23:48:14 GMT 2016 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar
  4596 Tue Dec 13 18:09:14 GMT 2016 BOOT-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
 66802 Thu May 28 09:49:34 BST 2015 BOOT-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

The log4j(1) support was dropped with Spring Boot 1.3 (see [Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes)). Thus you probably do not have the log4j jar on the classpath. But adding just the jar to the classpath will not bring back the Spring Boot log4j support.

So either consider to use supported logging frameworks, rollback Spring Boot to a version below 1.3 (not really recommended) or make log4j(1) work with Spring Boot 1.5.

**Update**: As I notice now you are not using log4j1 (which I assumed first) but already log4j2. That is OK. In this case you probably have to follow the Spring Boot instuctions on how to [Configure Log4j for logging](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging).

Sorry for pointing you in the wrong direction...

Comment: I never explicitly tell Spring Boot to use log4j. The error just popped out out of nowhere. How do I tell Spring Boot to use lets say slf4j ?

Comment: The question is what your code (or the libraries you use) are using as logging framework. Somewhere log4j seems to be used - and if so - you will have to provide the library to avoid ClassNotFoundExceptions. The logging configuration properties of Spring Boot will probably not work. Have a look at the [logging](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging) documentation of Spring-Boot. Beware of the fact that log4j**2** is meant when log4j is mentioned.

Comment: The fix was to remove `comsat-tomcat-loader` which uses log4j (thanks to you). And to extend my Spring Boot application with `SpringBootServletInitializer ` as mentioned in http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html.

Comment: So this answer barely answered your question. I would recommend to put your fix in an own answer and accept this one.